# Understanding the scale transform

Tags: svg

Please help me better understand SVG scale. So far, from what I understand about the scale, `scale(2)` will scale the SVG to twice it's original size. Is this correct?

If so, what would `scale(43,1)` do? As in the below (in a D3 code):

```
var barGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate(100,30) scale(43,1)')
    .attr('class','bar');
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with D3 scales. That's just the `scale` in the `transform` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform I edited your question removing [tag:d3.js] and adding [tag:svg].

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I was making an incorrect assumption and was querying google for D3 scale and not finding the correct information which is svg scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It scales 43 times X and 1 time Y.

`scale(2)` has only one parameter but is the same as `scale(2,2)`.

> `scale(<sx> [<sy>])`, which specifies a scale operation by sx and sy. If `<sy>` is not provided, it is assumed to be equal to `<sx>`.
>
> [SVG 1.1 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute)

Comment: Thanks for the link llobet.

Comment: Your welcome. I think it is also a complete explanation, which is always useful.